# Flutter on Digital Ocean

Tags: flutter, digital-ocean

I am a beginner Flutter app developer(IOS, ANDROID) and have been learning by creating apps that have DB on Firestore. I am wondering is it possible to integrate flutter app with DigitalOcean DB(using MySQL). If not, Is there any other service to use SQL?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do this by using restful APIs. In flutter there are many packages to get and post data etc from Apis like [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) , [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) etc.